# How to get size of elements which is dynamically added to DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some list which elements is adding to DOM dynamically after some JS action - in this case photos from FileReader. After this i need to count this elements for some other action, but simple:

```
var photoUploadBoxThumbs_count = $('#js-photoUploadBoxThumbs li').size();
console.log(photoUploadBoxThumbs_count);
```

does't work. Can anybody help?

Comment: What does that mean *"does't work"* ? Did you debug ? What happens ?

Comment: what jquery version are you using? did you try with `.length`?

Comment: [`.size`](http://api.jquery.com/size/) is deprecated as of jQuery 1.8

Comment: photoUloadBoxThumbs_count, p is missing :)

Comment: lenght does't work, i have 2.0 version of jquery, i don't any response in console

Comment: @Hacketo this is only a writing mistake

Comment: Can you make a Fiddle? `.length` works fine in jQuery 2. Can you show more of your code, maybe you put it in the wrong place?

Comment: Why i get `-` votes for this question? Is it to stupid?

Comment: @putvande this is a tones of code, i need to get this number after another file input change action...

Comment: What jQuery version are you using? The .size() method is deprecated as of jQuery 1.8.

Comment: i said that before: 2.0

Comment: is the #js-photoUploadBoxThumbs element a div ?

Comment: Should work, you should try to execute $('#js-photoUploadBoxThumbs li').size(); directly in the console, when your element should be available in the DOM and see what's happen

Answer (score 1):

`$('#js-photoUploadBoxThumbs li').length` and `$('#js-photoUploadBoxThumbs li').size()` works for me.

Check the event on which you are firing the code to calculate length.

---

**For example :**

file 'change' in case of file input or Ajax 'success' in case you are getting the images.

Comment: thank you @R3tep for editing the code. Getting used to the answering guidelines.